# position hyperlink near right edge of the div

Tags: css, positioning, dreamweaver

I have three hyperlinks, I want to position them near the right edge of the div. 
This div is positioned within another div, called mainHeader. 
Here is what I have:

```
<div class="mainHeader">
<div id="Buttons">
<a href="#" class="myButton">New Customer</a>
<a href="#" class="myButton2">Sign In</a><br />
<input type="text" />
<a href="#" class="myButton3">Go</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css is this one so far:

```
.mainHeader
{
    background: #b2b2b2;
    height:60%;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

So, I want all those four controls to be positioned near the right edge of the div 'mainHeader'. 
The first two links, myButton and myButton2 should be in one row, and below them there should be the textbox and the other button.
Any idea how I can solve this?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I just changed the position of the textbox with the button and then added the `direction:rtl;` css rule to the `mainHeader` class.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QHuv3/

If your mainHeader div wraps more than just the Buttons div and you don't want the `direction:rtl;` css rule in it, then you could do this:

```css
.mainHeader, #Buttons
{
    background: #b2b2b2;
    height:60%;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#Buttons
{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

The HTML should have the textbox and button places switched as well.

Fiddle for this second case:
http://jsfiddle.net/QHuv3/1/

Answer (score 0):

this should do it. you'll want to change the widths/margins accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/YYaP2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'more classic' solution (http://jsfiddle.net/vUzBg/):

HTML:

```
<div class="mainHeader">
    <div id="Buttons">
        <div class="top">
            <a href="#" class="myButton">New Customer</a>
            <a href="#" class="myButton2">Sign In</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <input type="text" />
            <a href="#" class="myButton3">Go</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainHeader
{
    background: #b2b2b2;
    height:60%;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.top, .bottom {
    float: right;
}
.bottom {
    clear: right;   
}
```